# Direction in `framer-motion`

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

How we can reverse direction of `framer-motion` implemented animation?

This is My Component, and This change `background` of box element from `#000` to `#ff0` :

```
import React from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import type { Variants } from 'framer-motion';

const variants: Variants = {
    initial: { background: '#000' },
    animate: { background: '#ff0' },
};

export function Box(props: Props = { isMenuActive: false }) {
    return (
        <motion.div initial='initial' animate='animate' variants={variants}>
            Hi
        </motion.div>
    );
}

type Props = {
    isMenuActive: boolean;
};
```

##### BUT

direction of this animation is from `initial` to `animate` namespace, but i want if `props.isMenuActive` was `true`, then, animation execute from `animate` to `initial` namespace, exactly direction of animation reversed.

#### Example

In `anime.js` library, we can use this snippets to reverse direction : [documention of `anime.js`](https://animejs.com/documentation/#reverseAnim)

**NOTE** : `anime.js` didn't support `jsx` and `react`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

am not sure whether framer-motion has a reverse function but you can do it yourself with this logic:

```
 initial: { background: isMenuActive ? '#000' : '#ff0' },
    animate: { background: isMenuActive ? '#ff0' : '#000' },
```